# How to fix 'Texture doesn't exist in any known resource pack' error? [Minecraft 1.20 modding]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I had to restart for the like tenth time due to something breaking in IntelliJ and me being unable to fix it. I have followed the guide I always do when restarting since it always works, but now I am having an issue where IntelliJ isn't detecting my textures.

To give an idea of my code here is my ModBlockStateProvider datagen class:

```java
package net.KaiHallow.magicalcraft.datagen;

import net.KaiHallow.magicalcraft.MagicalCraft;
import net.minecraft.data.PackOutput;
import net.minecraft.resources.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.RotatedPillarBlock;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.generators.*;
import net.minecraftforge.common.data.ExistingFileHelper;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;

import static net.KaiHallow.magicalcraft.block.ModBlocks.*;

public class ModBlockStateProvider extends BlockStateProvider
{
    public ModBlockStateProvider(PackOutput output, ExistingFileHelper exFileHelper)
    {
        super(output, MagicalCraft.MOD_ID, exFileHelper);
    }

    @Override
    protected void registerStatesAndModels()
    {
        blockWithItem(BLUE_CRYSTAL_BLOCK);
        blockWithItem(DEEPSLATE_LIGHTNING_CRYSTAL_ORE);
        blockWithItem(LIGHTNING_CRYSTAL_ORE);

       logBlock((RotatedPillarBlock) ANCIENTWOOD_LOG.get());

        axisBlock((RotatedPillarBlock) ANCIENTWOOD_WOOD.get(), blockTexture(ANCIENTWOOD_LOG.get()), blockTexture(ANCIENTWOOD_LOG.get()));

        axisBlock((RotatedPillarBlock) STRIPPED_ANCIENTWOOD_LOG.get(), new ResourceLocation(MagicalCraft.MOD_ID, "block/stripped_ancientwood_log"),
                new ResourceLocation(MagicalCraft.MOD_ID, "block/stripped_ancientwood_log"));
        axisBlock((RotatedPillarBlock) STRIPPED_ANCIENTWOOD_WOOD.get(), new ResourceLocation(MagicalCraft.MOD_ID, "block/stripped_ancientwood_log"),
                new ResourceLocation(MagicalCraft.MOD_ID, "block/stripped_ancientwood_wood"));

        blockWithItem(ANCIENTWOOD_LEAVES);
        blockWithItem(ANCIENTWOOD_PLANKS);
        saplingBlock(ANCIENTWOOD_SAPLING);

        simpleBlockItem(ANCIENTWOOD_LOG.get(), models().withExistingParent("magicalcraft:ancientwood_log", "minecraft:block/cube_column"));
        simpleBlockItem(ANCIENTWOOD_WOOD.get(), models().withExistingParent("magicalcraft:ancientwood_wood", "minecraft:block/cube_column"));
        simpleBlockItem(STRIPPED_ANCIENTWOOD_LOG.get(), models().withExistingParent("magicalcraft:stripped_ancientwood_log", "minecraft:block/cube_column"));
        simpleBlockItem(STRIPPED_ANCIENTWOOD_WOOD.get(), models().withExistingParent("magicalcraft:stripped_ancientwood_wood", "minecraft:block/cube_column"));
    }

    private void blockWithItem(RegistryObject<Block> blockRegistryObject)
    {
        simpleBlockWithItem(blockRegistryObject.get(), cubeAll(blockRegistryObject.get()));
    }

    private void saplingBlock(RegistryObject<Block> blockRegistryObject)
    {
        simpleBlock(blockRegistryObject.get(),
                models().cross(Objects.ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS.getKey(blockRegistryObject.get())).getPath(), blockTexture(blockRegistryObject.get()).renderType("cutout"));
    }
}
```

For some reason the ONLY file it has an issue with where it does this is the `blue_crystal_block.png` file, if I have it as `blue_crystal_block.png` the image of the file for some reason turns into like a white document logo with a blue question mark in the top left corner of it, and the file cannot be opened in IntelliJ, can someone explain why this is happening to that file specifically (it works just fine if I have it spelled with any sort of typo or whatever just for some reason that specific set and order of characters it has an issue with, it even works if the file type is a webp type, just can't be found by the code.)

I've even tried to edit it externally through file explorer, removing it and replacing it, moving to another folder outside the project and back, cutting and pasting, editing the name and the suffix, nothing works. I mean it's not a big deal but it's still frustrating especially since now I'll have to sit here and deal with one of my files being forced to have a typo.